# Quantify impact of multiple local noisy predictors on global prediction accuracy? (picture for clarification)

Tags: probability, classification, prediction, error, accuracy

Have a general question that I'm uncertain of how to pose directly, and will instead pose graphically, so apologies for any misuse of terminology!

My question is how much better will my prediction of an object become if I include multiple noisy predictors of different sub-features of that object. Is the gain negligible if the local predictors are very error prone?

For a clearer example, let's say I have a bunch of simple pictures of animals, and I want to predict if the current picture is a human. To do this, I have trained multiple local predictors to look at the picture and predict if the image has some feature of humans with the following errors:

- Torso (predictor error = 10%)
- Legs (predictor error = 15%)
- Head (predictor error = 20%)
- Hands (predictor error = 30%)
- Eyes (predictor error = 40%)
- Toenails (predictor error = 80%)

[image]

Then I predict that the image is that of a human based on the combined probabilities of the individual predictors. E.g. to be human, the image must have a torso, legs, head, hands, eyes, and toenails.

How can I quantify/express how useful it is to include a noisy predictor like toenails given how poor its predictive power is? I'm assuming that all these predictors are independent.

Thanks!